# Enum option not covered

Tags: rust

```
enum Shot {
    Bullseye,
    Hit(f64),
    Miss
}

impl Shot {
    fn points(self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Shot::Bullseye => 5,
            Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3.0 => 2, 
            Shot::Hit(x) if x >= 3.0 => 1, 
            Shot::Miss => 0
        }
    }
}
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Shot::Hit(_)` not covered
  --> src/main.rs:23:15
   |
23 |         match self {
   |               ^^^^ pattern `Shot::Hit(_)` not covered
   |
note: `Shot` defined here
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
13 | enum Shot {
   |      ----
14 |     Bullseye,
15 |     Hit(f64),
   |     ^^^ not covered
```

Comment: advice to not use guard pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust doesn’t attempt to check the `if` branches for exhaustivity, and because of this it sees you as missing the default value for `Shot::Hit(x) => todo!(),`.

In this case the solution would be to remove the second `if`, and to have just:

```
match self {
    Shot::Bullseye => 5,
    Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3.0 => 2, 
    Shot::Hit(x) => 1, 
    Shot::Miss => 0
}
```

Comment: As explained in @AlexanderKrauze's answer, this will evaluate to `1` in the case of `Shot::Hit(NaN)` which might not be intended.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here. First is with non exhaustive match arms, and second with floating point numbers. To talk about them separately let us change `Shot::Hit` variant to hold `i32` instead of `f64`.

```rust
enum Shot {
    Bullseye,
    Hit(i32),
    Miss
}

impl Shot {
    fn points(self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Shot::Bullseye => 5,
            Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3 => 2, 
            Shot::Hit(x) if x >= 3 => 1, 
            Shot::Miss => 0
        }
    }
}
```

This still won't compile with very similar error message. This is because rust is not "smart" enough to see that those two arms are indeed exhaustive. Idiomatic way to tell to rust that they are, is to add branch `Shot::Hit(_)` and telling that it is `unreachable!`

```rust
match self {
    Shot::Bullseye => 5,
    Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3 => 2, 
    Shot::Hit(x) if x >= 3 => 1,
    Shot::Hit(_) => {
        unreachable!("all integers are either greater that 3 or less or equal to 3")
    }
    Shot::Miss => 0
}
```

If this branch is matched at runtime then program will panic, which is usually a proper thing to do (since this **must** be a bug).

However if we go back to floating point numbers this still won't be enough. And the culprit is of course `NaN` (the reason why `f32/64` implement only`PartialEq` and `PartialOrd` and not `Eq` and `Ord`).

You will have to decide if `NaN` is value you allow `Shot::Hit` to hold or not. If it is **impossible** you could ignore this case and just use `unreachable!`. But if this can happen, you should match against that case as well

```rust
match self {
    Shot::Bullseye => 5,
    Shot::Hit(x) if x < 3 => 2, 
    Shot::Hit(x) if x >= 3 => 1,
    // Note that we cannot say `if x == f64::NAN`, since `NaN != NaN`.
    Shot::Hit(x) if x.is_nan() => todo!(),
    Shot::Hit(_) => unreachable!("we should be clear now"),
    Shot::Miss => 0
}
```